# C++ Two Dimensional std::vector best practices

Tags: c++, vector

I am building an app that needs to have support for two dimensional arrays to hold a grid of data. I have a class `Map` that contains a 2d grid of data. I want to use vectors rather than arrays, and I was wondering what the best practices were for using 2d vectors. Should I have a vector of vectors of MapCells? or should it be a vector of vectors of pointers to MapCells? or references to MapCells?

```
class Map {
private:
    vector<vector<MapCell>> cells;

public:
    void loadMap() {
        cells.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
            //How should I be allocating these?
            vector<MapCell> row(HEIGHT);
            for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
                //Should I be dynamically allocating these?
                MapCell cell;
                row.push_back(cell);
            }
            cells.push_back(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what way of doing this is going to get me in the least amount of trouble (with respect to memory management or anything else)?

Comment: I wouldn't use `vector<vector<...> >` unless you want ragged edged arrays

Comment: I will want ragged arrays, but I could used padding on the ends to achieve this.

Comment: How you considered Boost.MultiArray? See what the docs say: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_introduction

Comment: That should be *"Have" you considered [..]*

Comment: I have a two-dimensional array class [here](https://github.com/r-barnes/grid_engine) which may suit your needs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you want a square or 2d grid, do something similar to what the compiler does for multidimensional arrays (real ones, not an array of pointers to arrays) and store a single large array which you index correctly.

Example using the Matrix class below:

```
struct Map {
private:
  Matrix<MapCell> cells;

public:
  void loadMap() {
    Matrix<MapCell> cells (WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
        // modify cells[i][j]
      }
    }

    swap(this->cells, cells);
    // if there's any problem loading, don't modify this->cells
    // Matrix swap guarantees no-throw (because vector swap does)
    // which is a common and important aspect of swaps
  }
};
```

Variants of matrix classes abound, and there are many ways to tailor for specific use.  Here's an example in less than 100 lines that gets you 80% or more of what you need:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<class T, class A=std::allocator<T> >
struct Matrix {
  typedef T value_type;
  typedef std::vector<value_type, A> Container;

  Matrix() : _b(0) {}
  Matrix(int a, int b, value_type const& initial=value_type())
  : _b(0)
  {
    resize(a, b, initial);
  }
  Matrix(Matrix const& other)
  : _data(other._data), _b(other._b)
  {}

  Matrix& operator=(Matrix copy) {
    swap(*this, copy);
    return *this;
  }

  bool empty() const { return _data.empty(); }
  void clear() { _data.clear(); _b = 0; }

  int dim_a() const { return _b ? _data.size() / _b : 0; }
  int dim_b() const { return _b; }

  value_type* operator[](int a) {
    return &_data[a * _b];
  }
  value_type const* operator[](int a) const {
    return &_data[a * _b];
  }

  void resize(int a, int b, value_type const& initial=value_type()) {
    if (a == 0) {
      b = 0;
    }
    _data.resize(a * b, initial);
    _b = b;
  }

  friend void swap(Matrix& a, Matrix& b) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(a._data, b._data);
    swap(a._b,    b._b);
  }

  template<class Stream>
  friend Stream& operator<<(Stream& s, Matrix const& value) {
    s << "<Matrix at " << &value << " dimensions "
      << value.dim_a() << 'x' << value.dim_b();
    if (!value.empty()) {
      bool first = true;
      typedef typename Container::const_iterator Iter;
      Iter i = value._data.begin(), end = value._data.end();
      while (i != end) {
        s << (first ? " [[" : "], [");
        first = false;
        s << *i;
        ++i;
        for (int b = value._b - 1; b; --b) {
          s << ", " << *i;
          ++i;
        }
      }
      s << "]]";
    }
    s << '>';
    return s;
  }

private:
  Container _data;
  int _b;
};
```

Comment: +1, but some things I would do differently: I would provide a no-argument constructor that builds an empty matrix, and a three argument constructor with second dimension defaulting to 1 and default initial value to allow user code to do `Matrix a(5)` and get a one dimensional matrix of size 5 (instead of an empty matrix as the code above). I think `clear()` should apply the vector swap technique to release the acquired memory: `swap( _data, Container() )`. Both `operator[]` should return references instead of pointers.

Comment: What's the advantage of having
    typedef T value_type ?

Comment: @David:  op[] returns pointers so you can use m[a][b].  Its purpose is illustrative and for first approximations, so while I don't necessarily disagree with your ctor and swap suggestions, I hesitate to add too much complication.  (The repr inserter is borderline, but less common, so the complication has higher value IMHO.) -- @fabrizioM: Same advantage as having vector<int>::value_type---I'm using a subset of the STL sequence interface, and it could easily be expanded to include more of it.

Comment: @Roger Pate: right, I had not noticed that you provide `matrix[a][b]` syntax. I have grown used to think on `operator()` better than `operator[]` for accessing the elements. There is a nice discussion in the C++FAQ recommending `operator()` with 2 arguments instead of providing the double `[]` syntax here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.11

Comment: @David: I disagree with that FAQ entry, but that seems better discussed in a new question than in comments here.  However, almost none of that FAQ applies to this class, since the intent (though it wasn't explicitly mentioned) is to be a 2d analogue to std::vector.  Much of the class has been stripped out, as I tried to just include the essentials so the implementation is as understandable as possible.  (I really did over-simplify the ctors as you first noticed though, easy enough to make them less confusing than the version with all default arguments.)

Comment: One question about this though. Is it a better idea to use a vector<MapCell*> or a vector <MapCell&> or a vector<MapCell>? I understand that the later holds all the information in one contiguous block of memory, so that would probably end up being faster, but what is the size limit? Also, what would the scope of the values be? If my vector holds MapCell Objects, would there be an issue if I allocated local variables in a load method and added them to teh vector?

Comment: @goatlinks: My code uses a vector<MapCell> (indirectly, passing MapCell as T and then using vector<T>).  (A container of pointers just isn't appropriate here.  A container of references is not allowed in C++.)  The size is limited by available contiguous memory.  The vector is a data member of the Matrix class, so lives "within" that object.  When you "add" them you copy into the vector, so that's not a problem.

Comment: There is something that I am missing in this code. If I want to add a column or a column, will I need to 'reorder' all the elements of the matrix?

Answer (score 3):

If the whole matrix has a mostly constant width and height, you may as well use a single `vector`, and address cells with `(row * columnCount) + column`. That way the whole thing will be stored in a single memory block instead of in several fragmented blocks for each row. (Though of course you are doing the right thing to wrap this concept up in a new class - I'm just talking about the behind-the-scenes implementation.)

A vector of vectors has the unfortunate property that if you insert a row at the top, `std::vector` will perform a copy construction (or assignment, possibly) for all the other rows as it shifts them down by one place. This in turn involves reallocating the storage for every row and individually copying the items in the cells of every row. (C++0x will probably be better at this.)

If you know that you will be doing that kind of thing often, the advantage of a single large memory block is that you can insert a new row at the top and `std::vector` will only have to shift all the cells forward by `columnCount` places, so it will seriously reduce the number of heap operations (freeing/reallocating of individual blocks).

Although as you suggest, a vector of pointers to vectors would have the further advantage that it would only need to shift forward a lot of pointer values, and the size of the block containing all the row pointers will be much smaller, further lessening the impact of heap operations.

Of course, the only way to be sure of the actual impact of these things on the performance of an application is to time it with various implementations and compare them. This is why you're doing exactly the right thing by hiding these details inside a new class.

Answer (score 1):

Use a vector and translate the 2 dimensions to one dimension.
E.g. if your matrix has a width of W and a height of H, then mapping x,y to the index in the vector is simply x*W+y.

If your matrix is sparse you may want to use an std::map where the key is a pair (x and y).

Answer (score 0):

In my projects I often use this [simple grid class](http://code.google.com/p/xulwin/source/browse/trunk/XULWin/include/XULWin/Grid.h).