# Dynamic matrix with contiguous storage

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I want a matrix container class that has similar functionality to vector<vector<type>>, but stores elements in contiguous memory. I bet there is none in the standard library (including C++0x); does Boost provide one?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2286991/54262

Comment: Are all the _inner_ `vector` s guaranteed to be the same size?

Comment: @Motti: unfortunately not, otherwise I would continue to use vector of std::array

Comment: @Motti: it seems I misread your question, yes, all inner vectors  will be the same size (just like matrix - number of elements in row is the same for each row).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want the misleadingly-named [Boost Matrix](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm).

> The templated class matrix is
>   the base container adaptor for dense
>   matrices. For a (m x n)-dimensional
>   matrix and 0 <= i < m, 0 <= j < n
>   every element mi, j is mapped to the
>   (i x n + j)-th element of the
>   container for row major orientation or
>   the (i + j x m)-th element of the
>   container for column major
>   orientation.

Comment: Just tried and it seems that it doesn't alloc elements in contiguous memory. Do you have any experience in using it that you can share? Especially how can I get a pointer for data stored by such matrix? Using &my_matrix.data() (in STL it's just my_vector.data()) gives me a segfault and I'm stuck with &matrix(0,0) ...

Comment: @erjot - Interesting. That more or less directly contradicts the quoted section above. To be honest, I figured it was going to be the "dynamic" part that would cause you grief, not the "contiguous".

Comment: Boost.Matrix is being created in row-major order by default and I needed column-major order, that's why it wasn't working - hint found on other SO topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think Boost.MultiArray does what you want.